# Multiple Columns in an "in" statement

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am using DB 2 and i am trying to write a query which checks multiple columns against a given set of values.Like field a, field b and field c against values x,y,z,f. One way that i can think for is writing same condition 3 times with or i.e. `field a in ('x','y','z','f') or field b in .... and so on` . Please let me know if there is some other efficient and easy way to accomplish this. I am looking for a query like if any of the condition is true return yes else no . Please suggest !

Comment: @NageshKumar It's quite often a risky proposition to say something can't be done ;-)  If you have enough bright creative looking at something they frequently find a way.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work on as400:

```
create table a (a int not null, b int not null);
insert into a (a,b) values (1,1),(1,3),(2,3),(0,23);

select a.* 
from a 
where a in (1,2) or b in (1,2);

A           B          
----------- -----------
          1           1
          1           3
          2           3
```

Rewriting as a join:

```
select a.* 
from a 
join ( values (1),(2) ) b (x) 
    on b.x in (a.a, a.b); 

A           B          
----------- -----------
          1           1
          1           3
          2           3
```

Comment: Are you serious? The create table statement is for sample data and has nothing to do with the solution.

Comment: yes.  I'm not following your answer at all.  Maybe it's the use of integers instead of characters.

Comment: The type of the column is completely irrelevant for whether it is possible to rewrite the query as a join.

Comment: I know.  Ok, I've been staring at this for a while and I think I'm following it now.  It works for the most part.  But it does have a (possible) problem in that duplicate rows are returned.

Comment: I checked the join solution on an IBM i 7.1 TR8 system and it works.  For the problem stated, it is the most succinct solution.

Comment: Most succinct per truest to the apparent intent to reduce the three identical predicates to just one.  However this example did not code *SELECT DISTINCT* to omit duplicates [if even that is acceptable for the minimally-described scenario; lacking any DDL, sample data, and sample <report> output].  And "if any of the condition is true return yes else no" was not satisfied either, though easily enough resolved by just changing JOIN to LEFT JOIN and add as part of the SELECT, the expression: CASE WHEN B.X IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS "In"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column data types are the same, Create a subquery joining all the columns you want to search with your IN into one column with a union

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT 
        YOUR_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY
        ,A AS Col
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        YOUR_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY
        ,B AS Col
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        YOUR_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY
        ,C AS Col
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
) AS SQ
WHERE
    SQ.Col IN ('x','y','z','f')
```

Make sure to include the table key so you know which row the data refers to

Comment: I see a couple problems with this...`UNION ALL` allows for duplicate rows.  `UNION` would prevent that.  But I suspect there would be a performance penalty.  Assuming the OP needs the entire row, joining back to the original table would also pay a price.

Comment: No need to join merely to get the "entire row"; just include YOUR_TABLE.* in each subselect of the UNION query as Nested Table Expression (NTE), in place of YOUR_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY.  Of possible additional value for that revised query [with the duplicates still included] is a capability to identify from which column was the matching value, rather than just an indicator yes\no; of course "no" values are not included. An additional column in the derived-table expression could be added after each "AS Col"; e.g. ", CHAR('Col_?') AS PerCol" for each "?" as, A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular expression that describe the set of characters and use it with xquery

Comment: How would you do this on DB2 for i?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a supported version of the OS (tested on 7.1 TR6), this should work...

```
with sel (val) as (values ('x'),('y'),('f')) 
select * from mytbl                          
where flda in (select val from sel)          
   or fldb in (select val from sel)          
   or fldc in (select val from sel)
```

Expanding on the above since your OP asked for "condition is true return yes else no"

Assuming you've got the key to a row to check, would 'yes' or the empty set be good enough?  `somekey` is the key for the row you want to check.

```
with sel (val) as (values ('x'),('y'),('f')) 
select 'yes' from mytbl                          
where thekey = somekey
   and ( flda in (select val from sel)          
        or fldb in (select val from sel)          
        or fldc in (select val from sel)
       )
```

It's actually rather difficult to return a value when you don't have a matching row.  Here's one way.  Note I've switch to 1=yes, 0=no..

```
with sel (val) as (values ('x'),('y'),('f')) 
select 1 from mytbl                          
where thekey = somekey
   and ( flda in (select val from sel)          
        or fldb in (select val from sel)          
        or fldc in (select val from sel)
       )
UNION ALL
select 0               
from sysibm.sysdummy1  
order by 1 desc        
fetch first row only
```